Smoothness of Matérn kernel
I want to find the number of smoothness of the Matérn Kernel, which means the maximum $s$ such that the function is $s_*=\lfloor s -1\rfloor$ times differentiable and the last derivative is $(s-s_*)-$Holder continuous. My trial:
$$h(x) = \frac{2^{1-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}\Bigg(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{x}{\rho}\Bigg)^\nu K_\nu\Bigg(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{x}{\rho}\Bigg)\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^+,\ \nu\in\mathbb{R}^+.$$
First, $K_\nu$, denoting the modified Bessel's function of second kind, can be written as
$$K_\nu(y)\propto I_{-\nu}(y)-I_\nu(y).$$
Here, $I_\nu$ denotes the modified Bessel's function of first kind, i.e.
$$I_\nu(y)=(y/2)^\nu\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(y/2)^{2k}}{k!\Gamma(k+\nu+1)}.$$
Here, we can note that, for $\nu\ge 0$, this function is infinitely times differentiable, as the denomianator, growing as $\approx (k!)^2$, makes the sum converge for every derivative. So, the part containing $I_\nu(y)$ does not affect differentiability, and can be erased. Focusing on the other part, called $\widetilde h$, we have
$$\widetilde h(x)\propto \Bigg(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{x}{\rho}\Bigg)^\nu I_{-\nu}\Bigg(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{x}{\rho}\Bigg)=\Bigg(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{x}{\rho}\Bigg)^\nu (\sqrt{\nu}x/(\sqrt 2\rho))^{-\nu}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\sqrt{\nu}x/(\sqrt 2\rho))^{2k}}{k!\Gamma(k-\nu+1)}$$
$$=2^\nu\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\sqrt{\nu}x/(\sqrt 2\rho))^{2k}}{k!\Gamma(k-\nu+1)}.$$
Now, if $\nu$ is not an integer, the denominator is well defined. Therefore, the argument of before applies, and as the denominator is $\sim (k!)^2$, the result of the sum is $C^\infty$.
Unfortunately, this result is False, as it is known that the Matérn kernel is only differentiable $m<2\nu$ times.
Where is themistake in my analysis?

$h(x)$ is analytic. The Matérn kernel is about a Gaussian process. Since this is a stochastic process it seems reasonable that analyticity might be lost

There was no error in my reasoning, just that when articles say "Matérn kernel is only differentiable $m<2\nu$ times" they refer to the kernel applied to $|x|$, which is not a $C^\infty$ function of $x$ obviously. Repeating my reasoning for $h(|x|)$ gives the desired result, as is done in this paper (Proposition 10)
